# How to get values from application.yaml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a application.yaml file that looks like this:

```
 config:
   level1:
    sub1:
      hostname:"abc.xyz.com"
      port:3000
    sub2:
      hostname: "www.xyz.com"
      port:3001
   level2:
    sub1:
      hostname: "www.abc.com"
      port: 3000
    sub2:
      hostname: "www.xyz.com"
      port:3001
```

So far I have tried using @ConfigurationProperties("config") and then tried to use a private variable of type `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>` to parse this but that doesn't work either.

How do I parse this type of file? I've tried pretty much everything I know. Im new to spring so any help with this would be great!

Comment: Please update your question with what you are currently trying and what specific issues/errors you are getting :)

Comment: you can inject the values directly, try the key by adding `.` on each level like to get sub1 hostname, you can use `@Value("${config.level1.sub1.hostname}")` on your property. If you do not want to inject the value , you can retrieve these value from Environmetn using key in similar pattern

Comment: Have you tried `@Value("${config}") Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> config;`?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson

Comment: don't forget to run ./mvnw clean package after updating your application.yml file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Value` annotation to get value from YAML file or Type-safe Configuration Properties to bind values, learning about the reference here, [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```